# Need to add custom column and rename values in a column

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I have 3 things I need to do with a sql I am using in Metabase

1. I need to add a column called owner that only has Daily Track n Trace in the fields
2. I have a column where I need to change the names that show example ABC Industry, I need to show as ABC
   `ShipmentListView`.`org_name` AS `org_name` so how do case when 'ABC Industry' = 'ABC'?
3. I would like the values from column in point 2 to be in a custom column so Column Subject will have ABC Industry.

Below example code I have done.

```
SELECT 
 
`S`.`order_id` AS `Haven_id`, 
`S`.`selectedVoyage_originEtd` AS `Original_ETD`, 
CAST(`S`.`selectedVoyage_destinationEta` as date) AS `Original_ETA`,
`S`.`selectedVoyage_originAtd` AS `Header_ATD`, 
`S`.`selectedVoyage_destinationAta` AS `Header_ATA`, 
`S`.`container_name` AS `container_type`, 
`S`.`fromPort_code` AS `fromPort_code`, 
`S`.`fromPort_country` AS `fromPort_country`,
`S`.`fromPort_name` AS `fromPort_name`, 
`S`.`fromPort_type` AS `fromPort_type`, 
`S`.`order_billOfLadingNum` AS `BL_Number`, 
`S`.`order_cargoReadyDate` AS `Cargo_Ready_date`, 
`S`.`order_carrierBookingNum` AS `Booking_Number`, 
`S`.`order_quantity` AS `Container_qty`, 
`S`.`order_status` AS `order_status`, 
`S`.`org_name` AS `org_name`,
`S`.`selectedVoyage_carrierName` AS `selectedVoyage_carrierName`, 
`S`.`toPort_code` AS `toPort_code`, 
`S`.`toPort_country` AS `toPort_country`, 
`S`.`toPort_name` AS `toPort_name`, 
`S`.`toPort_type` AS `toPort_type`, 
`S`.`vessel_name` AS `vessel_name`,
`S`.`Primary_Key`,
`S`.`EST_DATE`


FROM (SELECT (`ShipmentListView`.`order_id` + `ShipmentListView`.`org_id`) AS `Primary_Key`,
Cast(IF(`ShipmentListView`.`selectedVoyage_originEtd`IS NULL, `ShipmentListView`.`quoteCriteria_estimatedDate`, `ShipmentListView`.`selectedVoyage_originEtd`) as date) AS `EST_DATE`,
`ShipmentListView`.`order_id` AS `order_id`, 
Cast(`ShipmentListView`.`selectedVoyage_originEtd` as date) AS `selectedVoyage_originEtd`, 
Cast(`ShipmentListView`.`selectedVoyage_destinationEta` as date) AS `selectedVoyage_destinationEta`, 
cast(`ShipmentListView`.`selectedVoyage_originAtd` as date) AS `selectedVoyage_originAtd`, 
Cast(`ShipmentListView`.`selectedVoyage_destinationAta` as date) AS `selectedVoyage_destinationAta`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`container_name` AS `container_name`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`fromPort_code` AS `fromPort_code`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`fromPort_country` AS `fromPort_country`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`fromPort_name` AS `fromPort_name`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`fromPort_type` AS `fromPort_type`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`order_billOfLadingNum` AS `order_billOfLadingNum`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`order_cargoReadyDate` AS `order_cargoReadyDate`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`order_carrierBookingNum` AS `order_carrierBookingNum`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`order_delayComments` AS `order_delayComments`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`order_quantity` AS `order_quantity`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`order_status` AS `order_status`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`org_name` AS `org_name`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`selectedVoyage_carrierName` AS `selectedVoyage_carrierName`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`toPort_code` AS `toPort_code`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`toPort_country` AS `toPort_country`,
`ShipmentListView`.`order_isArchived` AS `order_isArchived`,
`ShipmentListView`.`toPort_name` AS `toPort_name`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`toPort_type` AS `toPort_type`, 
`ShipmentListView`.`vessel_name` AS `vessel_name`
FROM `ShipmentListView`)`S`

WHERE
 ((`S`.`order_status` = 'ADJUSTMENT_REQUESTED'
    OR `S`.`order_status` = 'ARRIVED_POD' 
    OR `S`.`order_status` = 'BOOKING_CONFIRMATION_PENDING' 
    OR `S`.`order_status` = 'DELIVERED' 
    OR `S`.`order_status` = 'DOCUMENT_PROCESSING' 
  )
   AND `S`.`order_isArchived` = FALSE
```

Comment: About point 1: Do you want to add a column to your database/table, or to your query?

Comment: Hi Peter... I want to just add it to the query, I understand how to add to the db but I don't have access to this

Comment: I worked it out I just add what I want to fill the column as the header I want in the select part.  eg. 'Daily Track n Trace' AS 'Owner'